# No Facetime On My iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, facetime

My problem is that I can't enable Facetime on my iPhone 4. I've searched this problem on many forums and they all say Facetime needs to be turned on in the Phone app's settings, or enabled in some other settings. The problem I have is that I literally have 0 Facetime settings, anywhere on my phone. (please see screenshots).

I have an iPhone 4. It was bought second had and the previous owner said he bought it from the UK. It is on iOS 6.1.2. When I bought it, it was on iOS 5 which I upgraded to iOS 5.1 and I did not have Facetime at the time either. I jailbroke my phone and used this Cydia tweak to get Facetime. http://www.iphonehacks.com/2010/10/how-to-enable-facetime-on-iphone-4-in-unsupported-countries-using-facetime-hactivator-middlewhat.html

It worked. My problem now is that I don't want to jailbreak my phone. I am on iOS 6.1.2 and it is likely that iOS 6.1.3 will not be jailbreakable. I want to get used to the idea of not having a jailbroken phone and I need a solution to my Facetime problem. I can provide any other information required.

This is what my settings look like:

[image]

Would really appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 1):

PK-UFONE is a Pakistani carrier.

Pakistan [is not listed](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3367) as a country that doesn't support FaceTime, but [some have similar problems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4277701?start=0&tstart=0) and can't use FaceTime:

> (Sep 8, 2012) i do not have facetime option on my iphone 4 with operating system IOS
>   5.1.1 please help me.

In another [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4206922?start=0&tstart=0) a user states:

> (Aug 14, 2012) I have bought my iphone 4s from Apple Store in Birmingham,UK.I am now
>   in Pakistan and connot use Facetime as the verification phone number
>   displayed is that of UK.

[Others](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2721263?start=0&tstart=0) successfully activated FaceTime, but activated it abroad:

> (Feb 3, 2011)
>   I am not sure if it will 'activate' on a carrier in Pak. Can only
>   share my experience that I hd similar situation but I activated it
>   before coming to Pak and FT worked just fine on Ufone carrier.

I'd recommend that you contact PK-UFONE. Maybe you simply need a different plan to activate FaceTime.

I doubt this will help, but you can also check this Apple article for troubleshooting: [iOS: Troubleshooting FaceTime](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3367).

There is a similar question related to an iPod [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84245/my-ipod-touch-5th-generation-doesnt-have-facetime/84249).

Answer (score 0):

If you country is in the UK you can switch it on by going to Settings > General > Restrictions and if it is switched OFF (which will be black/ no colour) select and click. Icon should turn green and you can use it. Also to update your device, borrow a computer from Apple or use your own to download iTunes from Apple.inc onto your computer/laptop and use the charger/ usb charger and plug into you laptop/computer and it will say that you can have the next update. Hope this was helpful.