# FaceTime not working on iPhone 6 Plus purchased from Dubai

Tags: iphone, facetime

I bought my iPhone 6 Plus in Dubai. I am using the phone in Sri Lanka and I cannot use the FaceTime. How can I use FaceTime while in Sri Lanka?

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, Facetime is not available on devices purchased in the United Arab Emirates and therefore in Dubai, as stated in these KB articles:

1. http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3367

   > FaceTime might not be available, or might become unavailable, on devices purchased or used in certain countries, including Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates.
2. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1937
   [image]

I recommend that you contact Apple support in Sri Lanka at http://www.apple.com/lk/support/contact/ or a local Apple reseller, they may be able to help you.

To find a reseller near you visit https://locate.apple.com/lk/en/sales/?pt=all&lat=6.9270786&lon=79.86124300000006, press `New Search`:

[image]

and type in your address.

Comment: Many (several) governments block messages and FaceTime, perhaps due to strong encryption, perhaps for other reasons. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84844/no-facetime-on-my-iphone-4 I doubt Apple would unlock or change those restrictions as it has to verify you aren’t in that region anymore and really can’t know who people are due to not tracking everything they could.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works out, You could jailbreak solution but it's just an option. This is just a suggestion. Jailbreaking has it's own set of pros and cons.

This issue can be fixed by updating the `carrier.plist` file. This requires your iPhone to be jailbroken on iOS 8.

- Download **CommCenter** tweak from Cydia from repo `apt.chinasnow.net`
- Install **iFile** from Cydia, now using iFile goto `/var/mobile/Library/Carrier Bundle.bundle`
- Open carrier.plist file using property list viewer, click on the "+" to add a new entry
- Type `AllowsVoIP` and set it type to *boolean* from *string* and create it
- Turn on `AllowsVoIP` in the carrier.plist file and click done

After you've done that reboot the iPhone and Facetime app should appear. If not, reboot the iPhone once more and check over at `Settings > General > Restrictions` for FaceTime option.