# Trying to find how to have FaceTime

Tags: facetime

Last July I went on a holiday to Dubai and have bought my very first iPhone from there, the Gold iPhone 6 plus. Recently I decided to start using Facetime but for some reason I cannot find the app. I am using my iPhone in Malta, in the middle of the Mediterranean with a Vodafone carrier.

Can anyone please show or explain how can I have FaceTime on my phone?

I tried finding various videos on YouTube but could not find the right one.

Comment: Have you tried pulling down on the screen and searching "FaceTime" in Spotlight? BTW, the icon is a big green rounded rectangle with a white camera in it.

Comment: iPhones bought in the UAE do not have FaceTime, as it is illegal in that territory.

Comment: Is there any way I can make facetime activated pls?!

Comment: Try setting your Region to Egypt.  If that does not work, you are out of luck, you bought your device in a place where this app in never provided and there is no way to fix it except maybe jailbreak.

Answer (score 2):

FaceTime is not available for iPhones purchased in the United Arab Emirates.

@jaume answered this question here: [FaceTime not working on iPhone 6 Plus purchased from Dubai](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150654/facetime-not-working-on-iphone-6-plus-purchased-from-dubai)

Answer (score -1):

I have the iPhone6 plus, I don't have an App for FaceTime, I added FaceTime access in contacts. (only works to other iPhone users)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have FaceTime? Perhaps you just don't notice it because you don't use it. FaceTime is a built in app and _all_ Apple devices (or at least those with cameras) have it.

Comment: @Arc676 Are you really not aware that FaceTime is never included in devices sold in certain countries?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that.