# Are there any differences between iPhone 7/7plus sold in different countries?

Tags: iphone

is there any quality difference between an iPhone bought in Dubai and an iPhone bought in USA? to be  precise, my question is about the quality of the gadget itself (hardware), because some of my friends claim that if you buy an iphone 7/7plus in USA, the quality of the gadget (resolution, camera, durability of the gadget) is way better than the one you buy in Dubai or any other country rather than USA. I HOPE this time i am more specific.
i am looking for your answers.

respect

Answer (score 2):

No such quality difference has been disclosed by Apple, nor do I know of anyone outside Apple discussing such a quality difference.

Answer (score 0):

iPhones that are purchased in Dubai dont have facetime, because you bought the phone in a country where facetime is restricted. However this [quora thread](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-FaceTime-on-an-iPhone-bought-in-Dubai) suggest you can always re-enable FaceTime, I am not sure though.This [apple.stackexchange.com question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150654/facetime-not-working-on-iphone-6-plus-purchased-from-dubai) however seems to be contradictory.

Comment: Similarly, iPhones sold in Japan are restricted so that you cannot turn of the "camera click" sound, since turning it off would be illegal there.

Answer (score 0):

There are difference between iPhone's between countries. Some use standard the GSM / CDMA network . You have to choose the one your telecom network supports. Also in Japan there seems to be some other chip inside the iPhone for NFC payment.

Also check out the Cellular / Wireless section on the [official iPhone 7 specs page.](http://www.apple.com/iphone-7/specs/)

Answer (score 0):

My friend works in the electronic field and knows that iPhone use different clips in different regions. Such as, use Qualcomm  clips in USA but Intel clips in Asia.